# Ubuntu Port wont listen to Client but will to Server

Tags: node.js, node-opcua

I am currently trying to run the server and the client between 2 different computers. However, the Server is working out fine but not the Client. I have tried to use sudo ufw port 4334 but to no avail. Can someone help me out.

```
 /*global require,console,setTimeout */
    var opcua = require("node-opcua");
    var async = require("async");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var csv = require("fast-csv");
    var sleep = require("system-sleep");

    var client = new opcua.OPCUAClient();
    var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://" + require("os").hostname() + ":4334/UA/MyLittleServer";


    var the_session, the_subscription;

    async.series([

        // step 1 : connect to
        function(callback)  {
            client.connect(endpointUrl,function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(" cannot connect to endpoint :" , endpointUrl );
                } else {
                    console.log("connected !");
            console.log("Endpoint URL ", endpointUrl);
                }
                callback(err);
            });
        },

        // step 2 : createSession
        function(callback) {
            client.createSession( function(err,session) {
                if(!err) {
                    the_session = session;
                }
                callback(err);
            });
        },

        // step 3 : browse
        function(callback) {
           the_session.browse("RootFolder", function(err,browse_result){
               if(!err) {
                   browse_result[0].references.forEach(function(reference) {
                       console.log( reference.browseName.toString());
                   });
               }
               callback(err);
           });
        },

        // step 4 : read a variable with readVariableValue
        //function(callback) {
        //   the_session.readVariableValue("ns=2000;s=TEST", function(err,dataValue) {
        //       if (!err) {
        //           console.log(" free mem % = " , dataValue.toString());
        //       }
        //       callback(err);
        //   }); 
        //},

        // step 4' : read a variable with read
        //function(callback) {
        //   var max_age = 0;
        //   var nodes_to_read = [
        //      { nodeId: "ns=2000;s=TEST", attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value }
        //   ];
        //   the_session.read(nodes_to_read, max_age, function(err,nodes_to_read,dataValues) {
        //       if (!err) {
        //          console.log(" free mem % = " , dataValues[0]);
        //       }
        //      callback(err);
        //   }); 
        //},


    //  function(callback){
    //      the_session.readVariableValue("ns=74;s=Dou", function(err,dataValue) {
    //          if(!err){
    //              console.log("Test Success", dataValue.toString());
    //          }
    //          callback(err);
    //          });
    //      },
    //
    //  function(callback){
    //      the_session.readVariableValue("ns=74;s=Float", function(err,dataValue) {
    //          if(!err){
    //              console.log("Test Success", dataValue.toString());
    //          }
    //          callback(err);
    //          });
    //      },
    //
    //  function(callback){
    //      the_session.readVariableValue("ns=74;s=String", function(err,dataValue) {
    //          if(!err){
    //              console.log("Test Success", dataValue.toString());
    //          }
    //          callback(err);
    //          });
    //      },

    //  function(callback){
    //      the_session.readVariableValue("ns=1;s=CSV", function(err, dataValue) {
    //          if(!err){
    //              console.log(dataValue.toString());
    //              sleep(5000);
    //          }
    //          callback(err);
    //          });
    //      },

    //  function(callback){
    //      the_session.readVariableValue("ns=1;s=CSV", function(err, dataValue) {
    //          if(!err){
    //              fs.createReadStream(dataValue.toString())
    //              console.log(dataValue.toString());
    //              sleep(5000);
    //                  .pipe(csv())
    //                  .on('data', function(data){
    //                  console.log(csv);
    //                  sleep(5000);
    //                  })
    //                  .op('end', function(data){
    //                  console.log("Read Finish")
    //                  });
    //          }
    //          callback(err);
    //      });
    //  },





        // step 5: install a subscription and install a monitored item for 10 seconds
        function(callback) {

           the_subscription=new opcua.ClientSubscription(the_session,{
               requestedPublishingInterval: 1000,
               requestedLifetimeCount: 10,
              requestedMaxKeepAliveCount: 2,
               maxNotificationsPerPublish: 10,
               publishingEnabled: true,
              priority: 10
           });

           the_subscription.on("started",function(){
               console.log("subscription started for 2 seconds - subscriptionId=",the_subscription.subscriptionId);
           }).on("keepalive",function(){
              console.log("keepalive");
           }).on("terminated",function(){
               callback();
           });

           setTimeout(function(){
               the_subscription.terminate();
           },10000000);

           // install monitored item
         var monitoredItem  = the_subscription.monitor({
               nodeId: opcua.resolveNodeId("ns=2000;s=TEST"),
               attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value
           },
           {
               samplingInterval: 100,
               discardOldest: true,
              queueSize: 10
           },
           opcua.read_service.TimestampsToReturn.Both
           );
          console.log("-------------------------------------");

         monitoredItem.on("changed",function(dataValue){
              console.log(" New Data Receive = ",dataValue.value.value);
           });
        },

        // close session
        function(callback) {
            the_session.close(function(err){
                if(err) {
                    console.log("session closed failed ?");
                }
                callback();
            });
        }

    ],
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(" failure ",err);
        } else {
            console.log("done!");
        }
        client.disconnect(function(){});
    }) ;
```

Comment: Assuming this works when both the client and the server are on the same host (so the client URL says localhost), then it must be a generic network issue. Things to consider: the server listening only on the loopback interface; server firewall blocking incoming connections to port 4334; client firewall blocking outgoing connections. It would also help posting the exact error the client gets.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to edit the endpoint URL so it points to the correct machine.

In your example, the client is trying to address a server running on the same machine.

```
  var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://" + require("os").hostname() + ":4334/UA/MyLittleServer";
```

Assuming your opcua server is running on port 4334 on a machine named ServerMachine with IP 192.1.2.3:

You need to specify:

```
 var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://ServerMachine:4334/UA/MyLittleServer";
```

or

```
 var endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://192.1.2.3:4334/UA/MyLittleServer";
```